# Tensor notation generally

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, tensors, covariance

I'm pretty new to tensors in differential geometry and I have a basic question about the notation used. In general a vector field $X$ can be expressed as

$$X=\sum_{i=1}^n X^i \partial_i,$$

where $X^i = v(x^i)$ is the vector-coordinate and $\partial_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_p, \ v \in T_p (M)$ is the basis.

Likewise, a one form $\theta$ can be written as

$\theta = \sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i dx^i$,

again, where $\theta_i = \theta(\partial_i)$ is the coordinate and $dx^i$ is the (dual) basis (please correct me if any of the above is wrong). What confuses me is that an (r,s)-tensor $A$ can then be written as

$A=\sum A_{j_1,...,j_s}^{i_1,...,i_r} \partial_{i_1} \otimes ... \otimes \partial_{i_r} \otimes dx^{j_1} \otimes ... \otimes dx^{j_s} $,

Where $j_1,...,j_s$ are my covariant components (vector fields) and $i_1,...,i_r$ are my contravariant components (one-forms). Why does the notation seemingly change with respect to the basis? Here, it looks like $\partial_{i_1} \otimes...\otimes \partial_{i_r}$ is my contravariant (dual) basis and $dx^{j_1} \otimes ... \otimes dx^{j_s}$ is my covariant basis? Is this just a notation tradition or am I missing something? Can anyone explain exactly what the basis terms do in terms of operations in the last expression, in case I am off? Thanks a million.

Comment: Perhaps you want to clarify--the $i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_r$ are indices; they simply label a component. They are not contravariant components *in and of themselves*. - Do you understand that the $X^i$ in your example of a vector field are contravariant components?  And yes, that they do go with the *covariant* basis vectors?

Comment: anyone should start using the Einstein's sum convention $$X= X^i \partial_i$$ to simplify "idioms"

Comment: @janmarqz No.${}$

Comment: @AloizioMacedo, no? just because? ... don't be shy, tell us why